# Xamarin Forms DisplayPrompt apply Keyboard renderer

Tags: xamarin.forms

My goal is to add an OK button on **iOS** numeric keyboard; I can achieve that very easily with a custom renderer :

```
public class ExtendedEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Element == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Check only for Numeric keyboard
        if (this.Element.Keyboard == Keyboard.Numeric)
        {
            this.AddDoneButton();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>Add toolbar with Done button</para>
    /// </summary>
    protected void AddDoneButton()
    {
        var toolbar = new UIToolbar(new RectangleF(0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f, 44.0f));

        var doneButton = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, delegate
        {
            this.Control.ResignFirstResponder();
            var baseEntry = this.Element.GetType();
            ((IEntryController)Element).SendCompleted();
        });

        toolbar.Items = new UIBarButtonItem[] {
            new UIBarButtonItem (UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace),
            doneButton
        };
        this.Control.InputAccessoryView = toolbar;
    }
}
```

but my question is how can we add this keyboard behavior on a Xamarin prompt dialog.

```
await DisplayPromptAsync("Title", "Content", keyboard: Keyboard.Numeric);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to customize the Keyboard of **AlertView** in iOS , you could implement it by using **DependencyService**

#### in Forms

create a Interface

```
public interface IDisplayPrompt
{
   void DisplayPrompt(string Title,string Content,Keyboard keyboard,Action<string> SubmitAction,Action CancelAction);
}
```

#### in iOS

```
using System;
using app55;
using app55.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using UIKit;
using System.Drawing;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(DisplayPromptImplement))]
namespace app55.iOS
{
    public class DisplayPromptImplement:IDisplayPrompt
    {
        public DisplayPromptImplement()
        {
        }

      

        public void DisplayPrompt(string Title, string Content, Keyboard keyboard, Action<string> SubmitAction, Action CancelAction)
        {
            UIAlertController alertController = UIAlertController.Create(Title,Content,UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

            UIAlertAction OKAction = UIAlertAction.Create("OK",UIAlertActionStyle.Default,(action)=> {

                //click OK Button

                var content = alertController.TextFields[0].Text;

                SubmitAction.Invoke(content);
            });

            UIAlertAction DismissAction = UIAlertAction.Create("Cancel", UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, (action) => {

                //click Cancel Button

                CancelAction.Invoke();
            });

            alertController.AddTextField((field)=> {

                if (keyboard == Keyboard.Numeric)

                    field.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad;
                    AddDoneButton(field);
                });

            alertController.AddAction(OKAction);
            alertController.AddAction(DismissAction);

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(alertController,true,null);
        }


        protected void AddDoneButton(UITextField field)
        {
            var toolbar = new UIToolbar(new RectangleF(0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f, 44.0f));

            var doneButton = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, delegate
            {
                field.ResignFirstResponder();
                              
            });

            toolbar.Items = new UIBarButtonItem[] {
            new UIBarButtonItem (UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace),
            doneButton
        };
            field.InputAccessoryView = toolbar;
        }
    }
}
```

Now in Forms we could invoked it like following

```
   void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Device.RuntimePlatform=="iOS")
        {
            DependencyService.Get<IDisplayPrompt>().DisplayPrompt("Title", "Please Input Message", Keyboard.Numeric, (content) =>
            {
                /// get the content that you input
                label.Text = content.ToString();

            }, null);
        }

        else
        {
            // other platform
            //...await DisplayPromptAsync
        }
    }
```

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zt1ef.png)